# Extracting all the emojis from a string using REGEX

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match, preg-match-all

I have been trying to extract all the emojis from a string using a regex function listed below. However, this function is not accurate sometimes as it adds up additional emojis in the process.
The regex that I am using is this one:

```
preg_match_all('/([0-9|#][\x{20E3}])|[\x{00ae}|\x{00a9}|\x{203C}|\x{2047}|\x{2048}|\x{2049}|\x{3030}|\x{303D}|\x{2139}|\x{2122}|\x{3297}|\x{3299}][\x{FE00}-\x{FEFF}]?|[\x{2190}-\x{21FF}][\x{FE00}-\x{FEFF}]?|[\x{2300}-\x{23FF}][\x{FE00}-\x{FEFF}]?|[\x{2460}-\x{24FF}][\x{FE00}-\x{FEFF}]?|[\x{25A0}-\x{25FF}][\x{FE00}-\x{FEFF}]?|[\x{2600}-\x{27BF}][\x{FE00}-\x{FEFF}]?|[\x{2600}-\x{27BF}][\x{1F000}-\x{1FEFF}]?|[\x{2900}-\x{297F}][\x{FE00}-\x{FEFF}]?|[\x{2B00}-\x{2BF0}][\x{FE00}-\x{FEFF}]?|[\x{1F000}-\x{1F9FF}][\x{FE00}-\x{FEFF}]?|[\x{1F000}-\x{1F9FF}][\x{1F000}-\x{1FEFF}]?/u', $string, $emojis);
```

When I try to print 'emojis[0]' after this, sometimes, it is not accurate.

For example,

CODE:

```
$string = "Get into it !!! ";
preg_match_all('/([0-9|#][\x{20E3}])|[\x{00ae}|\x{00a9}|\x{203C}|\x{2047}|\x{2048}|\x{2049}|\x{3030}|\x{303D}|\x{2139}|\x{2122}|\x{3297}|\x{3299}][\x{FE00}-\x{FEFF}]?|[\x{2190}-\x{21FF}][\x{FE00}-\x{FEFF}]?|[\x{2300}-\x{23FF}][\x{FE00}-\x{FEFF}]?|[\x{2460}-\x{24FF}][\x{FE00}-\x{FEFF}]?|[\x{25A0}-\x{25FF}][\x{FE00}-\x{FEFF}]?|[\x{2600}-\x{27BF}][\x{FE00}-\x{FEFF}]?|[\x{2600}-\x{27BF}][\x{1F000}-\x{1FEFF}]?|[\x{2900}-\x{297F}][\x{FE00}-\x{FEFF}]?|[\x{2B00}-\x{2BF0}][\x{FE00}-\x{FEFF}]?|[\x{1F000}-\x{1F9FF}][\x{FE00}-\x{FEFF}]?|[\x{1F000}-\x{1F9FF}][\x{1F000}-\x{1FEFF}]?/u', $string, $emojis);
print_r($emojis[0]);
```

OUTPUT:

Array ( [0] =>  [1] =>  [2] =>  )

This is not expected as the second element in the above array was not in the inputted string.

Is this a REGEX issue? Is there any better REGEX for this? Or anything other than REGEX to extract emojis?

Answer (score 2):

Your are dealing with "Fitzpatrick Modifiers".

I haven't had a close look at your regex pattern to make refinements, but I can offer a quick solution.

Use: `(?:[\x{1f3fb}-\x{1f3ff}](*SKIP)(*FAIL))|` at the start of your pattern disqualify the modifiers.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/KJNWd))

```
$string = "Pregnant Woman:  Pregnant Woman:  Fork and Knife:  Light Skin Tone:  (a pale skin tone modifier)";
//$string = "Get into it !!! ";
    preg_match_all('/(?:[\x{1f3fb}-\x{1f3ff}](*SKIP)(*FAIL))|[0-9|#][\x{20E3}]|[\x{00ae}|\x{00a9}|\x{203C}|\x{2047}|\x{2048}|\x{2049}|\x{3030}|\x{303D}|\x{2139}|\x{2122}|\x{3297}|\x{3299}][\x{FE00}-\x{FEFF}]?|[\x{2190}-\x{21FF}][\x{FE00}-\x{FEFF}]?|[\x{2300}-\x{23FF}][\x{FE00}-\x{FEFF}]?|[\x{2460}-\x{24FF}][\x{FE00}-\x{FEFF}]?|[\x{25A0}-\x{25FF}][\x{FE00}-\x{FEFF}]?|[\x{2600}-\x{27BF}][\x{FE00}-\x{FEFF}]?|[\x{2600}-\x{27BF}][\x{1F000}-\x{1FEFF}]?|[\x{2900}-\x{297F}][\x{FE00}-\x{FEFF}]?|[\x{2B00}-\x{2BF0}][\x{FE00}-\x{FEFF}]?|[\x{1F000}-\x{1F9FF}][\x{FE00}-\x{FEFF}]?|[\x{1F000}-\x{1F9FF}][\x{1F000}-\x{1FEFF}]/u', $string, $emojis);
print_r($emojis[0]);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 
    [1] => 
    [2] => 
)
```

Comment: Fails on ‍♂️— identifies two emojis:  and ♂️

Comment: Can that be mitigated? I don't often play with this range of "text".  I don't know why I have a pipe in my character class, I don't typically make this mistake.  Must not have had a coffee back then.

Comment: It's difficult for me to test/dev on regex101 because when I paste ‍♂️ into the input box, the split occurs.

Comment: @BobbyJack  After a quick glance at some documentation of the sequence, I reckon that the issue is borne from the fact that the Fitzpatrick Modifier is not at the beginning of the sequence?  https://emojipedia.org/man-facepalming-type-1-2/  If you are battling this issue yourself, perhaps rearrange the pattern's sequence.  I also recommend omitting all pipes from character classes and applying the `x` pattern modifier so that the pattern can be distributed across multiple lines of code (improving readability).

Comment: I didn't really have enough time on the train to have a proper look.